# JavaScript stop script if a condition is not met

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript file to which I send a parameter

```
   <script lang="en" src="/test/load.js" ></script>
```

In the file I have script similar to this:

```
  ! function()
{ some code 
  var lag   = ( script.getAttribute( 'lang' ) == null  || script.getAttribute( 'lang' ) == '' ) ? exit : script.getAttribute( 'lang' );
```

The idea is that I do not want to execute the code after the one quoted above in case that parameter 'lang' is missing or is an empty string. How can I do that, I tried using

```
 exit
```

or

```
 break
```

but they do not work for me.

Comment: What about `return`?

Comment: ... and please don't use the `?:` operator for statements. The ? Operator is  used for expressions. `{ /* some code */; var lang=script.getAttribute('lang'); if (lang==null) return; if (strlen(lang)==0) return; /* more code */ }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the main problem is that you're trying to use the conditional operator as a sloppy alternative to an `if` statement.

Just use an `if` statement, with `return`:

```
var lang   = script.getAttribute('lang');
if (!lang) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the problem was I was trying not to use an if-statement which, obviously, was a mistake. Thanks! I wrote it like this: `if ( script.getAttribute( 'lang' ) == null || script.getAttribute( 'lang' ) == '' )
 {
  return;
 }
 else var lang = ( script.getAttribute( 'lang' ) );`

Comment: I would add that the ternary operator is not a 'sloppy alternative' -- it's simply being misused.  It's designed to evaluate an expression, when in fact no expression needs evaluating, rather, a statement (`return`) needs to be executed.  I'm upvoting your answer, so I'm not critiquing, just clarifying that the ternary operator is not sloppy in and of itself, but a misuse of anything will result in problems.

Comment: @Josh Yes, the operator is great when it's used for the correct purpose, but some people use it when they really should be using an `if` statement, just to save a few keystrokes, and that is sloppy.

Answer (score 1):

**use this after your statement**

```
return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's code within a function, correct?  How about `return`?

Comment: if it isn't code within a function you can always make it to be in a function.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to stop script

```
return false;
```